# How to fix default ripple effect when changing button colours in Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I've noticed whenever you change the colour of a Button in Jetpack Compose, it will have an unnoticeable ripple effect.

I'd like to be able to keep the default grey-ish ripple effect and just have it overlay with my button colour of my choice.

For example:

```
Button(
  colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(containerColor = Color.Red),
  onClick = { }
)
```

The moment you change the colour, your button doesn't have the default ripple effect seen on most components.

To be clear, it does have some sort of ripple, but it isn't noticeable.

It looks like there's some lower level code calling `Modifier.clickable` on a `Surface` which has some sort of `indication` parameter or something that affects the ripple colour?

Is it possible to simply change the button colour but just keep the default ripple?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ripple color is defined by the `LocalRippleTheme`.
If you want to provide a custom color you can use:

```
    CompositionLocalProvider(LocalRippleTheme provides MyRippleTheme ) {

        Button(
            colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(containerColor = Color.Red),
            onClick = { }
        ){}
    }
```

with:

```
private object MyRippleTheme : RippleTheme {

    @Composable
    override fun defaultColor() = Color.Green

    @Composable
    override fun rippleAlpha(): RippleAlpha = RippleTheme.defaultRippleAlpha(
        Color.Green,
        lightTheme = true
    )
}
```